# Add values in column for based on name in different column python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with a column that has participants' full names, and another column  that has the attendance for a specific year. each participant's name appears multiple times with their attendance for that year. I want to add the attendance values for a specific person to see how many times they attended total. Right now I am using this command but it adds all the values in the attendance column.

```
StudentinfoAll['Attendance_x'].sum(axis=0)
```

How do I edit this so that it gives me the sum of the attendance values for a specific person? Thank you for your help.

Here is what my data frame looks like
Here is what it looks like

```
Full Name  Attendance  Question 1  Question 2
Dan Smith      4         3.0           2.0
Erika Jones    5         6.0           0.0
Dan Smith      3         5.0           7.0
Erika Jones    5         5.0           3.0
```

Comment: For a specific student you can use a conditional index, e.g.: `StudentinfoAll[StudentinfoAll['Name'] == '<name>']['Attendance_x'].sum()`

Comment: I tried this and I got that the sum was 0 when it should be 26

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the total by student (not just for one student at a time), you need a group by operation.  For example, with a `test.csv` input of:

```
Full Name,Attendance,Question 1,Question 2
Dan Smith,4,3.0,2.0
Erika Jones,5,6.0,0.0
Dan Smith,3,5.0,7.0
Erika Jones,5,5.0,3.0
```

And some aggregation code of:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
print df.groupby('Full Name').agg({'Attendance': np.sum})
```

you get the following output (attendance by full name):

```
             Attendance
Full Name              
Dan Smith             7
Erika Jones          10
```

Comment: This alphabetised the names, and moved the attendance column, but it didn't give me the sum of the attendance values

Comment: Can you post a sample of `StudentinfoAll`?  Hard to debug otherwise.